How can I display ipywidgets button in Py-script?
    from pyscript import display
import ipywidgets as widgets
button = widgets.Button(description="Click Me!")
display(button)
The above is the main.py code of the Py-script.Using IPython.display it displays button in jupyter notebook.How can I re-write the same code in Py-script?

I'm not sure of your ultimate goal/need here? Are you are aware that ipywidgets works in JupyterLite and Voici? These use pyodide as the kernel basis, which pyscript shares as how it runs the Python.

I am able to import ipywidgets in pyscript was checking if I could work on it in pyscript.Just started with button display.

I do know that the current version you have to do some handling to get Panel widgets to get displayed now, see example at https://pyscript.com/@examples/kmeans-in-panel/latest . I haven't seen what you'd need for the equivalent for ipywidgets.

Thanks for helping @Wayne. HTML displayed the button of me display(HTML('submit')). I will try using it instead of ipywidgets.

I would caution you to use the current button system in the examples of pyscript, such as here. There's been a lot of changes over the years. py-button no longer is the way, see here.

I will surely bookmark your suggestion.
